# "mangling" namespaces/package names for xml beans classes

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema, xmlbeans

I have an xml that I need to consumde form java code,a nd think xml beans makes a lot of sense.  The input xml file has no namespaces, and I cannot modify the xml input format.

I used [trang](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/05/28/generate-xsd-from-xml/) to transform the xml to an xsd, then the xmlbeans-maven-plugin to generate java class from the xsd.  This works great, however, I'd like to put the generated classes into a specific package of my choosing, and I can't figure out a good way to do that, other than to add a namespace (which I can't do because that would require changing the input xml file).

I feel like there is probably an easy solution to this that I'm simply not seeing.

Answer (score -1):

and almost as soon as i posted this, i found this.

http://wiki.apache.org/xmlbeans/XmlBeansFaq#configPackageName